# How to pass arguments to a function inside compose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a function like so:

```
export const fireView = (prop1, prop2) => WrappedComponent =>
    class extends Component {
    //stuff in here
}
```

then a hoc like this:

```
export const withFireView = (prop1, prop2) =>
    fireView(prop1, prop2)
```

but now I want to put this function inside compose as I need to call it with `mapStateToProps`

so I did this:

```
compose (
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    fireView
)
```

but it breaks because `You must pass a component to the function returned by connect`

so I then I get rid of the arguments in the fireview function and I think this will work but then all the arguments are now undefined inside the function as I've not passed them

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
compose (
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    fireView(arg1, arg2)
)
```

but obviously, they are not defined there if that makes sense.

Comment: Consider adding more context and tags so it's obvious what you are referring to. What language/framework is this?

Comment: @Willeman I've added redux, react and javascript. what else is needed?

Comment: @RedBaron shou should have a deeper read on the docs. compose is a enhacer for the store https://redux.js.org/api/compose. connect adds dispatch and state to your props. https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: @di3 I understand that, I just want to add arguments to one of the functions I'm wrapping in compose

Comment: no you dont udnerstand that. sry connect has nothing todo with compose. the way you use react-redux is wrong. the way you use compose is wrong too.

Comment: `export const fireView = (prop1, prop2) => WrappedComponent =>` is supposed to be used like `compose (...,
 fireView(arg1, arg2)`. What problem do you have with that? It's unclear what's the purpose of `withFireView`. It basically does the same as `fireView`. `fireView` is already a HOC.

Comment: @di3 it really isn't. I don't think you've studied higher order components before.I never said connect had anything to do with compose

Comment: @estus ok lets ignore the `with` function. if I want to use the `fireView` function with compose, im still unclear how I pass in arguments to it/

Comment: Like `fireView(arg1, arg2)`, as you already showed. `compose` expects a HOC, i.e. a function that accepts a component as a param and returns a component. `fireView(arg1, arg2)` returns such function.

Comment: @estus yes but when I do `compose(fireView(arg1, arg2))` it says arg1 and arg2 are undefined...

Comment: I also don't know what the args as I'll be calling this function many times and passing in different args

Comment: @estus I intend to call the function like so: `export default fireView('somearg', 'anotherArg')(ARandomComponent)` and then in many other components

Comment: If I understood you correctly, it should be `const withFireAndConnect = (arg1, arg2) => compose(
 connect(mapStateToProps),
 fireView(arg1, arg2)
)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full working example:

```js
var Component = React.Component;
var render = ReactDOM.render;
var Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
var connect = ReactRedux.connect;
var createStore = Redux.createStore;
var compose = Redux.compose;
    
const reducer = () => {return {}};
const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return {}; 
};
    
const wrapped = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.prop1} {props.prop2}</div>;
}
const fireView = (prop1, prop2) => WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} />; 
    }   
  }
} 
    
const withFireView = (prop1, prop2) => fireView(prop1, prop2);
    
const withFireViewAndConnect = (arg1, arg2) => compose(connect(mapStateToProps), withFireView(arg1, arg2));
    
const App = withFireViewAndConnect('some', 'arg')(wrapped);
    
render(<Provider store={createStore(reducer)}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('demo'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.13.0/polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.1/redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/6.0.0/react-redux.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement and ended up on this page. I supposed we were not able to understand the use case. I will try to summarise it and also provide an answer to it.

**Explanation**

We can use [HOC (Higher Order Components)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) in React to abstract out common functionality. In React docs, we can see the 'with' notation to use these HOCs. I have created a few on my app as well.

```
withSplashScreenRedirect, withHistoryObject
```

All these HOCs that I created takes a Component (*WrappedComponent*) and returns a Component. (No additional Arguments required).

> const EnhancedComponent = higherOrderComponent(WrappedComponent);

I would generally have around 2 to 3 HOCs on each Screen level Component. Writing these HOCs as functions returning other functions look ugly. Redux provides a useful [compose](https://redux.js.org/api/compose) function. Compose helps us to chain these HOCs in a more readable manner.

From compose docs.

> All compose does is let you write deeply nested function transformations without the rightward drift of the code. Don't give it too much credit!

Soon I wanted to create another HOC that would standardise my API call logic and API call handling logic. In this case, I had to send two additional functions to my HOC (along with the Wrapped Component).

```
withApiCallHandler(WrappedComponent, makeApiCall, handleApiResponse)
```

Passing props to HOC is not a big deal. [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) have a good example explaining how to do it. However, adding such an HOC to compose chain is not so straightforward. I guess that is what OP was trying to ask here.

**Answer**

I wasn't able to find a way to chain such a HOC with compose. Maybe it's not possible. The best solution would be to initialise the withApiCallHandler Component separately and then chain it with compose.

Instead of

```
const ComposedScreenComponent = compose(
  withHOC1,
  withHOC2,
  withHOC3(arg1, arg2)
)(ScreenComponent);
```

Do this

```
const withHOC3AndArgs = (WrappedComponent) =>
  withHOC3(WrappedComponent, arg1, arg2);

const ComposedScreenComponent = compose(
  withHOC1,
  withHOC2,
  withHOC3AndArgs(arg1, arg2)
)(ScreenComponent);
```

*This is not the best answer to the question, but if someone is stuck then this solution will surely be a good workaround.*

Answer (score 0):

You can make `withFireView` return a function instead. All will work.

```
export const withFireView = (prop1, prop2) => () => fireView(prop1, prop2)
```